# Why we should use modulo multiplicative inverse in G.P. summation formula?

Tags: algorithm

Ques:
https://www.codechef.com/ISCC2018/problems/T24
Code which I referred:
https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/19340066

In this question we were supposed to find sum of a geometric progression.
while using summation of a Geometric Progression formula in cpp, why is there need to find modulo multiplicative inverse of K-1 ?Why cannot we directly divide by K-1?

Geomteric progression:
k+(k*k)+(k*k*k)+.....till n terms (where k is some integer)
Formula: (first term *(Cd raised to power n - 1))/(Cd-1).
Cd refers to common difference of Geomteric progression.

Comment: Is there any more context to this question? The answer is probably going to depend on it

Comment: The question is vague since there is no context. What is GP? Show the code for the function that uses the formula. Make sure to post a [mcve] that uses the function.

Comment: Did you mean `*(K-1)^-1`?

Comment: To sort-of answer the question without knowing any context: You can't just divide because `x%m / y%m != (x/y)%m`.

Comment: Sorry.Question updated.

Comment: Consider 4*4 mod 7 = 2, so to "undo" we'd want to find 2/4 = 4 - that's not how division in C++ works, multiplication by modular multiplicative inverse is something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by K-1 would give the correct answer if high precision integers are used.

The problem is that K to the power of N is going to be very large.  K can be up to a billion, and N up to a billion, so K to the power of N could be a 9 billion digit number.

However, only the result modulo a prime is requested so high precision integers can be avoided by doing all calculations modulo this prime.

Comment: This explains why the modulo, but not why the modulo multiplicative inverse. In particular, if "doing all calculations modulo this prime", why not just modulo-divide?

Comment: Division by x can be thought of as multiplying by the inverse of x.  For real numbers this means that dividing by 10 is the same as multiplying by 0.1.  For modulo numbers this trick also works and is commonly used because the slow inverse only has to be done once and then divisions can be done using the fast multiply part.